# What are inexpensive options for repairing unbootable Windows Vista after losing disk?

Tags: windows-vista, oem, system-repair-disc

My desktop computer running Windows Vista has stopped booting. Even in safe mode, it loads a bunch of drivers, then reboots. I would assume the OEM Vista disk would be able to repair this, but I cannot find the disk. Is there a way to download it for free? If not, what are some other options, without changing to another OS?

Update: I tried the instructions at [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120426200252AAmPoKe), but the directions are unclear and I can't tell whether the `.exe` I'm running is going to wipe out my working computer's Windows 7 installation.

Update 2: I found where the executable extracts the files, which is different than the directions. I may be on good path now.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail about your problem and your current condition? It might not be a result of OS.
EDIT: After a 5-sec lookup, I found about 10 answers on the Internet, so search before asking.

Comment: You will not regret upgrading to Windows 7 or Windows 8. Take the plunge and get away from Vista. Microsoft killed support for Vista before killing support for XP because it is that bad.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade to 7 or 8, ask your local computer repair shop for a disk. They will likely give you one.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options some of them require more technical knowledge than others.  If your computer is not booting, and you don't have the repair disks your options are limited.  For the non-technical, take it into a repair shop or the Geek Squad and they should be able to fix it for you.  Be aware that they don't always preserve your data and could charge you a chunk of change.

For the more technical user, I would first back up all your data, you can create a Linux Bootable CD or a flash drive and access all your files from there and copy them to a DVD or another flash drive, network location, the cloud, etc.

Although I don't condone illegal activity if you own a legitimate copy of Windows Vista (and lost the disk) you could download an ISO from just about any torrent site.

In a quick search I also found the link below which advertises free Vista recovery disks.

[Vista Recovery Disks](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2008/01/26/no-vista-installation-cd-you-can-still-download-a-vista-recover/)

Comment: I'm very technical. The problem is that the link you provided now costs $20, and I don't even know it's going to help.

Comment: I apologize for posting a paid link, I didn't follow it long enough to discover that it required payment.

Knowing that you're highly technical, boot to Linux, run "fsck", I would recommend downloading a real Vista repair disk and try some of the commands on there.

Answer (score 0):

The question is if it's illegal in his case? As he owns a license, isn't he free to get windows from whatever source he can and use that?

As it is quite a doubtful practice to link you through, I'm not going to. But you can acquire various iso's from various, doubtful, sources. Use an iso that clearly states it's unchanged and contains nothing but the official files and burn it to a disc, or boot it from USB if you're able to. (Sometimes an unaltered version is defined by the word 'proper').

I would put it in a comment, but my reputation does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal to make copies of Windows Discs, Vista or otherwise. Notice how it says on the discs "do not make *illegal* copies of this disc". If you have a valid licence and licence key, you can acquire a Vista Disc that has been copied to a Blank DVD without violating any laws.

That leaves you with many options. While software companies don't allow people to distribute ISOs on the internet (for various reasons one of them being customers give up and buy a new one), you aren't breaking any laws by downloading them (once again, if you have a licence). Even if you were to launch a website that distributes Vista ISOs for free, you would not be committing a crime, you would be infringing on the End User Licence Agreement, for which Microsoft needs to sue you in a Civil case. This is in the worst case scenario as a distributor of ISOs rather than as a downloader.

For windows 7, there are links floating around the internet which are directly from Microsoft's servers. This is sort of a truce / balance approach between making money from ignorant customers, while allowing technical people to reformat computers without resorting to unofficial sources for discs.